# Datagridview contents from 8 different tables? Vb.net MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

Is it possible to display selected data from 8 different tables to a datagridview in visual basic? I am using MS SQL. I have 1 table for president, 1 table for vice president, 1 table for secretary, 1 table for treasurer. 1 table for auditor, and 1 table for the business manager. Each table has five rows ID, PARTY LIST, NAME, GRADE, and VoteCount.

What I need to display to datagridview is party list, the pres. name, vice. pres. name, sec. name, tre. name and so on.

I would like to know if it is possible for datagridview.

Thanks.

Comment: You can bind one `DataTable` to a `DataGridView`.  It's up to you to decide how to populate that `DataTable`. If you want to do so with a query that joins 8 tables in your database then by all means do so.

Comment: Sounds like a faulty DB design.  One table for `Candidate` with a field indicating the position they are running for is all you need.  DB schemas are about *relationships*

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your column manually. I took this sample code from one of my app. it queries the format for each column from SQL and stores it in xgrid1 and xgrid2. one is the name of the column the other one is the Display name.
xgrid3 is the size of my column and xgrid4 is the alignment of the column. use whatever suits you. Once you have your columns setup then just runs you query and add rows to the grid using a loop. You cannot use datasource in your case.

use this to setup your grid

```
DG_Clients.Columns.Clear()
        DG_Clients.RowHeadersVisible = False

        For xcount = 0 To xgrid1.Length - 1
            DG_Clients.Columns.Add(xgrid2(xcount), xgrid1(xcount))
            DG_Clients.Columns(DG_Clients.Columns.Count - 1).Width = xgrid3(xcount)
            Select Case xgrid4(xcount)
                Case "L"
                    DG_Clients.Columns(DG_Clients.Columns.Count - 1).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
                    DG_Clients.Columns(DG_Clients.Columns.Count - 1).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
                Case "R"
                    DG_Clients.Columns(DG_Clients.Columns.Count - 1).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                    DG_Clients.Columns(DG_Clients.Columns.Count - 1).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                Case "C"
                    DG_Clients.Columns(DG_Clients.Columns.Count - 1).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                    DG_Clients.Columns(DG_Clients.Columns.Count - 1).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

            End Select
        Next
```

and use this to add to it

```
 Dim xRow As DataRow
        Dim xProvince As String
        For Each dRow As DataRow In DBAcc.DBDT.Rows
            Dim xlist(DG_Clients.Columns.Count - 1) As String

            For xcount = 0 To xgrid1.Length - 1
                Select Case xgrid2(xcount)
                    Case "Sex"
                        If dRow(xgrid2(xcount)) = 0 Then xlist(xcount) = "Male" Else xlist(xcount) = "Female"
                    Case "Province"
                        Select Case dRow(xgrid2(xcount))
                            Case 0
                                xProvince = "QC"
                            Case 1
                                xProvince = "On"
                            Case 2
                                xProvince = "NS"
                            Case 3
                                xProvince = "PEI"
                            Case 4
                                xProvince = "NF"
                            Case 5
                                xProvince = "MB"
                            Case 6
                                xProvince = "SK"
                            Case 7
                                xProvince = "AB"
                            Case 8
                                xProvince = "BC"
                            Case 9
                                xProvince = "NU"
                        End Select
                        xlist(xcount) = xProvince
                    Case Else
                        xlist(xcount) = dRow(xgrid2(xcount))
                End Select
            Next

            DG_Clients.Rows.Add(xlist)
        Next
```